# Is there any way to set majorUnit, minorUnit, minimum and maximum of my X-axis( category) or Y-axis (value) in apache poi 5.0.0?

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi

The following image is the output before setting the major and minor unit:
[image: current line chart]

I tried to set the majorUnit and minorUnit of my X-axis( category) in apache poi 5.0.0, By using the following code:

```
        XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
    leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MIN);
    bottomAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MIN);
    setValueAxisTitle(chart, 0, chartDataLocationInExcelFile.getColumnNames()[index + 1]);
    setCatAxisTitle(chart, 0, chartDataLocationInExcelFile.getColumnNames()[index - 1]);
    // getting minimum cat value of category 
    CellReference cellReference = new CellReference(chartDataLocationInExcelFile.getFirstRowNumber() + 2,
            chartDataLocationInExcelFile.getFirstCellNumber());
    Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
    Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol());
    // setting MajorUnit and MinorUnit of category axis  
    bottomAxis.setMajorUnit(0.2d);
    bottomAxis.setMinorUnit(0.3d);
    // setting minimum and maximum of category axis
    BigDecimal catMin = new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    BigDecimal subtractResult = catMin.subtract(new BigDecimal(5d));
    bottomAxis.setMinimum(subtractResult.doubleValue());
    //
```

Then it didn't work, And the following output generated:
[image: output after settings]
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible because of the lack of a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But MajorUnit and MinorUnit as well as Minimum are not useful for category axes. They are for value axes only, for scatter charts for example.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the source of XDDFCategoryAxis in Apache POI 5.0.0, I saw that setMajorUnit  and setMinorUnit didn't have body:

```
    @Override
    public void setMajorUnit(double major) {
        // nothing
    }
@Override
    public void setMinorUnit(double minor) {
        // nothing
    }
```

Comment: MajorUnit and MinorUnit as well as Minimum are not useful for category axes. They are for value axes only, for scatter charts for example.